# How to limit count of requests from one user with nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, nginx

I am developing rails application with contains two main parts:

- GET `/product/show/<product_id>.json` route
- POST `/search?query=<query>` route

Nginx is used as load balanser on production.
How can I make requests to these pages mo recure?

I want to limit access to these pages - no more then 3 requests per second by one user:

- user should be able to make only 3 searches per second
- user should be able to make only 3 product.json requests per second

How can I change nginx.conf to make it possible?

BTW, how can change nginx.conf to block scrapers and bots?

(to keep available api-access only for API users)

Thanks.

Comment: An alternative you might consider is the throttling functionality of the rack-attack gem https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#throttles

Comment: @BryceJohnston it's a big project with Chef and many server instances (apps, resque, search replication, db replication)... I think better to do this configurations on Nginx layer.

Comment: @BryceJohnston if this configs are on rails/rack layer it should work a little bit slower, shouldn't it?

Comment: Its rack middleware so its going intercept requests earlier on in the request/response cycle, but I'm guessing its slower than just purely using nginx modules. As for using it with a big project, Kickstarter builds/uses it.

Comment: See https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#performance

Comment: @BryceJohnston can you kindly write your rack `rack-attak` gem advise as answer? I found that it's the better solution for me :) also, I can limit user's requests, but is there a possibility to not block api_users (external service may make mass update in my DB via api etc.)

Comment: sure thing, added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a web server agnostic alternative, you might consider the throttling functionality of the rack-attack gem http://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#throttles

Its rack middleware so its going intercept requests earlier on in the request/response cycle, but I'm guessing its a little slower than just purely using Nginx modules. Bigger projects like Kickstarter use it so it should be pretty robust (see http://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#performance).

As for not throttling API users, you could completely ignore them inside of a whitelist block by inserting whatever logic is necessary to confirm that the request is from an authenticated API user/client session (see https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#whitelists).

Comment: what if external service, which send API request has dynamic IP? or it's IP address changes after each automation/release/build... can you kindly give me an example of code with blocking by userID or name?

Answer (score 1):

Edit this in nginx.conf:

```
server {

  location ~ /product/show/(.*)\.json$ {
     limit_req zone=one burst=3;
     proxy_pass youturl/product/show/$1.json ; 
  }

  location /search/ {
     limit_req zone=one burst=3;
  }

}
```

Or take a look here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Comment: does `/search/` mean only post requests? What means `zone=one` and `bursts=5`?

Comment: and what about GET `/product/show/<product_id>.json` ?

Comment: server {

    ...

    location /product/show/ {
        limit_req zone=one burst=3;
    }

Comment: but I need limit only `.json` requests, not standart html requests... Can you kindly update your answer to more detailed and better?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have opportunity to try, but following the guidelines of nginx should be so:

```
    location ~ /product/show/(.*)\.json$ {
    proxy_pass http://yoururl/product/show/$1.json ;
    limit_req zone=one burst=5;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot, last question - what means '$1'? it is an variable or regexp?